# Static variables within abstract generic class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I want to implement a variable which is static for each implementation of an abstract, generic class.
For example, I have the class...

```
public abstract class A<T>{
   ...
}
```

...and some implementations of A...

```
public class Imp1 extends A<Imp1>{
   static Imp1 myVar;
   ...
}
public class Imp2 extends A<Imp2>{
   static Imp2 myVar;
   ...
}
...
```

Is there any Keyword to implement myVar of Typ T in the abstract Class A? If I implement it as a static variable, it would give a TypeError since statics can't have the type T in abstract classes. If I implement it as an abstract, I can't call it from a static context like Imp1.myVar ... I don't think this is a duplicate of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198443/static-variable-in-an-abstract-generic-class), though I have to admit I did not quite understand it.

--EDIT--
Since it has been pointed out that this might be an XY-Problem and the answer seems to be that my approach can not be implemented, I'll try to describe the problem as a whole and try to work out how it should have been solved. Maybe this will help people restructure their code if they run into the same problem.
I wrote a class for my own datatype "Polynom" (mostly for practice and fun) with a couple of methods (add, multiply, divide, etc.). It is mainly based on a coefficient-list of doubles. Now, I wanted to change it, so a generic datatype could be used. I implemented an abstract class with all the required methods (adding, comparing, multiplying, calculating inverse, etc.). One of these is, that the datatype has a "neutral element", an element which has no effect on addition/multiplication. For example, if you implement real numbers, the neutral element should be 1 and 0. And this was the point I struggled with. At the moment I implemented the neural Element as a parameter for the polynomial-class, but I want to write other datatypes which also use generics and don't want to add them every time as parameter since they don't really belong there. I hope this was somewhat understandable, I'm happy to update the question further if it isn't.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do that? Static variables are almost always trouble.

Comment: For the following implementation:  
`public class MainClass<S extends A<S>> {S.someVar...}`  
If I implement it as a non-static, I would need to generate an Instance of S each time...

Comment: You haven't answered why you want it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, isn't it clear with my comment? I need it so I can avoid implementing it as a non-static, because to access it, I would need to create an instance which is possible, but not quite easy/efficient/pretty

Comment: Static fields and methods do not participate in inheritance. They are associated with their declaring class, and only that class. There is no way to enforce a class define a static field or method (at least not through normal means). If you declare a static field or method in a parent class, and then another field or method in a child class with the same name, the latter _hide_ (not override) the former. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hm, ok, that makes sense, but I don't really want to give 'foo' a value in 'A', I just want to force that all implementations of 'A' have a static variable 'foo' so I can reference it in implementations such as my example 'MainClass'

Comment: @MartinClever Since your is of variable type, it is not STATIC